# Permission Issue - Granting access to copy files with root ownership

Tags: permissions, file-copy

I have several files that are owned by root that I want to backup, using another user. I do not want to give this user access to all of root, just these particular directories and files.

Like `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`, etc..

How can I do this without granting root access to this particular user and still maintain ownership on the files?

I tried adding the specific files to the `/etc/sudoers.d/user_sudoers` without success.

```
user  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:       /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

In our shell script to create a daily backup I am calling...

```shell
cp -rp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /archive/DailyExport/today/httpd/ >> /archive/logs/DRLog.txt 2>&1
```

but I keep getting...

```
cp: cannot stat '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf': Permission denied
```

If I add `sudo` to my copy statement within my script...

```shell
sudo cp -rp /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /archive/DailyExport/today/httpd/ >> /archive/logs/DRLog.txt 2>&1
```

it prompts the user for the password to call sudo, which I want to run this from the cron so interactive is not going to work..

Comment: if I look at the /etc/sudoers file the script has already been defined                          
user ALL= NOPASSWD:  <path>/DisasterRecoveryExport.script

Comment: The last field in the sudoers file is a command, not a file name so including `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` does not add anything. You will need to allow the user to run the `cp` command as root. Please put in all sorts of safeguards here, including restricting any redirects.

Answer (score 1):

`sudoers` file is for specifying **commands** that the user can run as root (or as another user), using `sudo`. It has nothing to with file permissions.

To give an user access to files, you use the standard Unix/Linux permissions system.

Config files like `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` are usually on most systems readable for all users by default - it doesn't harm anything. You must have somehow restricted these permissions. You can simply make the file readable by all users again:

```
chmod a+r /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

You must also take care that all directories from `/etc/httpd/conf` (that is, this directory itself, `/etc/httpd` and `/etc`) are **accessible** (that is, have the `x` permission) for the user in question. Usually, they have so for all users by default, but if you did restrict it, you must set the permissions back, like for example:

```
chmod a+rx /etc /etc/httpd /etc/httpd/conf
```

(while having read permission for a directory is not strictly necessary to access its contents, it is necessary to **list** the contents, which the backup software may require - so it's better to assign both).

If you don't want to give read permissions to all users (however, I don't see the reason why), you can give permission only to this user. This can be done in two ways:

1. create a group to which only this particular user belongs, make all directories and files in question assigned to that group and give permission to the group, like:

   ```
    chgrp somegroup /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    chmod g+r /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
   ```
2. use ACLs to give permission for that particular user:

   ```
    setfacl -m -u:someuser:r /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
   ```

Of course the same rule of having `x` (or `rx`) permission for all parent directories applies.

Comment: I tried both options of adding the group and setfacl and neither worked.

Comment: You must have did something wrong. It is the most basic thing in the operating system and I have never seen it didn't work, if permissions are set correctly. Paste here output of `ls -l` commands showing what are the permissions on `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`, `/etc/httpd/conf`, `/etc/httpd` and `/etc`.

Comment: Why not going the simplest way (which doesn't harm any security) and make these files/directories world readable? It is set so by default in the operating system for a reason.

Comment: tried chmod -R +r /etc/httpd and chmod -R +r /etc/httpd/* but I am still receiving a Permission Denied message. The directories have drwxr-xr-x+   2 root ensadm, and the httpd.conf file has -rwxr--r-x+

Comment: If `ensadm` is the user running the backup, then it should work. Something that has permissions `rwxr-xr-x` is just readable for everyone. There must be some other reason. Is SELinux enabled? It might get in the way - if yes, try to disable it. Is the user `ensadm` able to read any file in `/etc` at all? Maybe it's some issue with the user itself.

Comment: It looks for me like you are trying to change too many things at once, which brings chaos. Try to investigate and change one thing at a time, until you find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: The chmod should have worked unless the script is being executed in chroot environment, or (if this RHEL or derived) SELinux.

Comment: The plus sign (+) in your directory permissions indicates existing ACLs for those directories.  Without information about those ACLs there is not much support anyone can offer.  What is the output of `getfacl /etc/httpd/ /etc/httpd/conf/ /etc/httpd/conf/http.conf`?  Any SELinux denials would be useful if it is enabled.

Comment: @GracefulRestart The ACLs probably come from the fact that the OP tried to implement all solutions from my answer at once (ie. make the files world readable, give read access to the group to which the backup user belongs and set ACLs for the backup user) - which is totally redundant as any of these three should be sufficient.